# How right to make function `print_text`?

Tags: python, pygame

I added the function `print_text` giving to write texts, but texts can't show on my program. Solve the problem, please)

```
pygame.font.init()
#[...]
def print_text(message, x, y, font_color = (0,0,0), font_type = 'shrift.ttf', font_size = 30):
    font_type = pygame.font.Font(font_type)
    text = font_type.render(message, True, font_color)
    display.blit(text, (x,y))
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    #[...]
    print_text('Hello, my friend!', 650, 100)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.font.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) needs to arguments. The font and the size:

<s>`font_type = pygame.font.Font(font_type)`</s>

```py
font_type = pygame.font.Font(font_type, font_size)
```

If [`pygame.font.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) doesn't work use [`pygame.font.SysFont`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont) instead:

```py
font_type = pygame.font.SysFont(font_type, font_size)
```

You are drawing black text in a black window. Change the color of the text. e.g:

<s>`print_text('Hello, my friend!', 650, 100)`</s>

```py
print_text('Hello, my friend!', 650, 100, "red")
```

Comment: Program shows mistake linked with display.blit. Do I have to change this function?

Comment: @Vildan What is the name of **your** display surface? (`... = pygame.display.set_mode()`)

Comment: Don't say! I've already found own mistake: I wrote screen.blit instead display.blit. Thanks a lot!